# PHP form redirect to a webpage

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I have an entry form that needs to redirect to a payment page, which I'm struggling to sort, here is my code:

```
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
         http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You For Entering. You need to make a payment now";
```

and this is what I want it to do:

```
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
         http_response_code(301); window.location='payment.html');
```

I know the below code won't work, I just can't see to code it correctly?

Is it possible?

Comment: Use PHP function header() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: window.location is javascript function .you need to use php header('Location: http://myhost.com/mypage.php');

Comment: People suggesting the usage of `header()` in these comments and answers are right, that's how you redirect in PHP - but the failed to mention that it **will not work** if you already had any output! Any HTML, whitespace, `echo`or `print` is output -- and will fail the usage of `header()`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use header function

```
if(@mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
             http_response_code(301); 
    header('location: http://yourdomain.com/payment.html');
```

Comment: Many thanks and although that is exactly what i want to do, it doesn't work either, so frustrating.

Comment: still no, think i will have to keep trying, thanks for your assistance tho.

Comment: @mail() will give you true or false;

Comment: i've managed to get it to forward to the html page by making, all the parameteers the same,                                                       http_response_code(302);
    header('location: http://www.mywebpage/entrypay.html');
        }